# I have an AJAX post request, how should my spring controller look

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, request

here is JS code:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/test/login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'loginEmail': loginEmail, 'loginPass': loginPass},
            success: function (data) {
                //do something
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert('Error ', err);
            }
        });
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/test")
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public HttpStatus login(@RequestParam String loginEmail, @RequestParam String loginPass){
        System.out.println(loginEmail);
        System.out.println(loginPass);
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }
```

}

I get this result:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg0cp.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jnHi.png)

and I go to the error block...

What should my controller look like so that I get into the success block?

P.S I do not use Spring Security

Comment: Please add the error details in your question.

Comment: @YuliiaZ I do not get a server error, please see the attached images

Comment: If XHR failed, you got an error. You need to post it here, not a screenshot of "failed".

Comment: @lux do you mean this? Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/test/login' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.